# Output of sensors on laptop

Tags: temperature

My Dell Laptop is suddenly running at around 70F according to `sensors` while previously it was at around 60.

This is under a medium amount of load, both temps.

Why? How would I cool it down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without more info, this is a hard one to diagnose. There are any number of reasons temp may have increased:

- The room temperature is higher than it was before.
- You have placed the laptop on an insulating surface.
- Your laptop has accumulated dust inside it.
- Your laptop's fan isn't running as well as it should.
- Your processor is working harder for some reason.

When I was in the desert, I would keep my laptop cool by placing it on four water bottle caps. This would allow air to circulate underneath it. You can also get a cooling pad for your laptop, or simply move it to a surface that conducts heat instead of insulating it. If it is an older laptop, have it cleaned and make sure the fan works well. Scan your laptop for malware and viruses, especially spyware, that may be using your processor. Defragment your HDD so that your processor doesn't spend as much time looking for data in secondary storage. Check your windows memory settings, and set them for optimum performance.

Comment: Laptop is on a pressed wood desk, same as before. room temperature is higher. 

I might look into cleaning the fan or a cooling pad.

Comment: Check your task manager also, to see if you have processes running in the background that are unnecessary.

Comment: This is even at startup. So, no.